# EntityFramework foreign key as primary key with fluent API

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to create a required:optional relationship between two entities, with the required entity exposing a navigation property to the optional entity, and the optional entity containing the foreign key, used as its primary key. This is what my two entities look like:

```
class OptionalEntity
{
  public string RequiredEntityID { get; set; }
}

class RequiredEntity
{
  public string ID { get; set; }
  public OptionalEntity Optional { get; set; }
}
```

And the way I would *like* to configure them in fluent API is as follows:

```
// Inside OptionalEntityConfiguration class
public OptionalEntityConfiguration()
{
  HasKey(r => r.RequiredEntityID);
}

// Inside RequiredEntityConfiguration class
public RequiredEntityConfiguration()
{
  HasKey(r => r.ID);
  HasOptional(r => r.Optional)
    .WithRequired();

  //  How can I configure this relationship to use
  //    the RequiredEntityID property as the foreign key?

  HasOptional(r => r.Optional)
    .WithRequired(o => o.RequiredEntityID);
  //  This is invalid because it requires a navigation property, not an ID

  HasOptional(r => r.Optional)
    .WithRequired()
    .HasForeignKey(o => o.RequiredEntityID);
  //  The HasForeignKey method isn't available here
}
```

**First of all is this possible, and if so what's the correct way to configure this relationship using fluent API?**

Comment: `HasOptional(r => r.Optional).WithRequired();` is enough. EF knows that `OptionalEntity` has `RequiredEntityID` as PK and its standard way of implementing 1-0..1 is by making this a PK/FK.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do is use the same key used on the Required Entity on the Optional Entity table, so that they share the same key.

If that is the case, I think you are on the right track. Your entity classes look alright. You can map them like these:

```
public OptionalEntityConfiguration()
{
   HasKey(r => r.RequiredEntityID);
   Property(r => r.RequiredEntityID)
      .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
}

public RequiredEntityConfiguration()
{
   HasKey(r => r.ID);
   HasOptional(r => r.Optional);
}
```

This implies, however, that there can only be 0 or 1 `OptionalEntity` for each `RequiredEntity`.

Comment: That's exactly the behaviour I'm looking for; each RequiredEntity has 0 or 1 OptionalEntity. Could you explain what the `HasDatabaseGeneratedOption` method does?

Comment: @AlfieWoodland, the [`HasDatabaseGeneratedOption`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh829109(v=vs.103).aspx) is the method for indicating how you want the value for the property (in this case the `RequiredEntityID`) to be set. Setting it to `None` means you do not want the database to generate it for you, and you will assign it yourself. You want to do this because, anyvalue for this column should really be coming from the `ID` of the parent record in `RequiredEntity`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<RequiredEntity>()
            .HasOptional(o => o.Optional)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(m => m.MapKey("RequiredEntityID"));
```

Comment: The `RequiredEntityID` property is exposed on the optional entity. Configuring the required entity like this causes the following validation error: `Each property name in a type must be unique. Property name 'RequiredEntityID' is already defined.`